# Django & MySQL unicode errors

Tags: mysql, django, utf-8

I am getting an `Incorrect string value (Exception Value: Incorrect string value: '\xEA\xB0\x95\xED\x95\x98...' for column 'object_repr' at row 1)` error while trying to save unicode string (Korean) in Django and MySQL.First problem I had was "Incorrect string value" error for each column in the database table. However, I figured this out by changing column collation and overall database character set.

The new error I am getting is related to **unicode**(self) method in models.py.My models.py is as the following:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
gender = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
location = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
captcha = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)

register_date = models.DateTimeField()
lastLogin_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
num_logins = models.PositiveIntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.full_name
```

The error is generated when the`__unicode__` function tries to output utf8 character...

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried applying the `smart_unicode` utility to `self.full_name` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#conversion-functions) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try add one line on the first of this file like this:

```
#-*- encoding=UTF-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 10):

In MySQL console execute

```
ALTER DATABASE django_db CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE django_admin_log MODIFY object_repr VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

For me it helps.

Comment: for making adminsite accept unicode - confirmed to work in django 4.0.4. This is required even after changing table and db charset.  Note in my case it varied slightly: `ALTER TABLE django_admin_log MODIFY object_repr VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;`

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by changing the file `settings.py`:  Don´t use `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'`.