# South django not working with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south

Django = 1.6.7

Pytyhon = 2.7.8

I can not make a syncdb with south installed.

if I point to ENGINE django.db.backends.sqlite3, if it works perfectly but when I switch to mysql does not work.

i have it ...

i have install Mysql , South

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'south',
)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'bag',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
        'PASSWORD' : '123',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PORT' : '3306'
    }
}
```

---

```
C:\Users\NEO\Desktop\APP\a>manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NEO\Desktop\APP\a\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute
_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242, in run_from_ar
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\south-1.0-py2.7.egg\south\management\commands\syncdb.py",
 89, in handle_noargs
    db.connection_init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\south-1.0-py2.7.egg\south\db\mysql.py", line 184, in conn
n_init
    if cursor.execute("SHOW variables WHERE Variable_Name='default_storage_engine';"):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 51, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 207, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 117, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xEDfico,...' for column 'Value' at row 1
```

Comment: Does not look like a problem with South but as the error states there is a problem with your character set for the DB type MYSQL on one of your columns.

Comment: but I'm not adding any application, only the "administrator", where I could see that, I'm using "appserv" as mysql server

Comment: I would take a guess here and say the database default character set is not utf-8 or the column is not. Check the mysql server make sure you are using utf-8 on both the db and/or the "Value" column.

Comment: this database as "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: what about the column it is having issues with "Value" that could be different.

Comment: also, try adding ``#-*- encoding=UTF-8 -*-`` to the top of the model file (first thing on the page)

Comment: I'm not building models, you are only creating the "admin" from django -----CREATE DATABASE  `bag` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: Well the error relates to it having problems with the character set within the database. Which is why it worked for one and not another. A quick search and have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497744/django-mysql-unicode-errors

Comment: the problem continues, my mysql has innodb, if I add the problem appears if south south off generates tables.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry and Thanks **Glyn Jackson**,

> and I could solve the problem, the problem was the mysql client used
>   server, used a version appserv as a server.
>
> I tried it on a production server and add tables and properly
>   migration.